# X-TAG: attributeChanged is not being on Firefox and Edge

Tags: x-tag

http://codepen.io/eeliya/pen/qNpBro

If you run this codepen demo on chrome, you will see an alert when you click the button.

But this does not work on Firefox or Edge. In other word `attributeChanged` is not triggered on FF and Edge

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this may be a bug in the WebComponents polyfill.  The work-around I have found for this issue is to use `setAttribute()` on the component, instead of direct assignment.  In other words, `component.setAttribute('active', true)` instead of `component.active = true`.